# Error: Unable to access the jar file kubernetes

Tags: spring-boot, docker, kubernetes

```
kubectl get pods
NAME                       READY         STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
stubs-v2-78b59ccc4f-85xgr   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   1        5m
Facing below error:

> ➜  ~ kubectl logs stubs-v2-78b59ccc4f-85xgr 
Error: Unable to access jarfile stubs.jar
```

The docker image is successfully running and my spring boot application is starting.

However, when I am trying to create a pod with this image, I am facing above mentioned error.

Tried running the `docker image`. It is running fine but getting error with `pod creation`.

Docker file [ The custom image has the user name and group configured and has the shell script to run the spring application]

```
FROM customimage

ENV APP_NAME=myapp \
    HOME=/home \
    LOG_DIR=/logs

RUN mkdir -p ${HOME} ${LOG_DIR} \
    && chown --recursive ${USER_NAME}:${USER_GROUP} ${HOME} ${LOG_DIR}

USER ${USER_NAME}:${USER_GROUP}

COPY target/*.jar ${HOME}/app.jar

EXPOSE 8080 9090 6566
ENTRYPOINT ["./spring_boot_app.sh"]
```

Deployment file[image-ref is the image created from the above docker file]

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: my-app
  namespace: custom-ns
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    app: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: app-stub
        image: image-ref
```

Comment: Are you using OpenShift by any chance? How is the question related to helm charts?

Comment: I am having using a helm chart to deploy the pod to my namespace

Comment: Please [edit] the post and add the (relevant parts of the) helm chart.

Comment: It does not have any dependent charts. I have just included values.yml and a deployment file in templates for clean deployment config

Comment: can you provide some more informations (.yml files of your pod, etc.), because at the moment it is impossible for us to solve your problem

Comment: I have updated the post and included the docker file and yml file

Comment: Does the image run with plain `docker run`, without Kubernetes?  What's in the `spring_boot_app.sh` script?

Comment: The issue is resolved. The error was with the user permission mentioned in the docker file. Added that user in the security context of the yml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the user mentioned in the DockerFile under the **security context** in the yml file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).